# remove all next divs after a child

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have something like this :

```
<div>
     <div class="productPage"></div>       
     <div>is hidden</div>  // ***this content will be hidden
</div>

// *** this one will not become hidden.
<div>not hidden..</div>
```

using this:

```
   $( ".productPage").nextAll().addClass( "hidden" );
```

This will hide only the content i marked on the code, means only childs of the same parent.
I need to hide every single thing after `productPage`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should also go to parent and target the next divs.

```js
$(".productPage").nextAll().addClass("hidden");
$(".productPage").parents("div").eq(0).nextAll().addClass("hidden");
```

```css
.hidden {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="productPage"></div>
  <div>is hidden</div> <!-- this content will be hidden  -->
</div>

<!-- this one will not become hidden. -->
<div>not hidden..</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This will break if the element has two div elements as parent like `<div><div>Element.</div></div>`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`Next Siblings Selector ~`](https://api.jquery.com/next-siblings-selector/) for this

This will select all elements following `.productPage` that have the same parent, and also match the `div` selector

```js
$(".productPage ~ div").addClass("hidden");
```

```css
.hidden {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="productPage"></div>
  <div>is hidden</div> <!-- this content will be hidden  -->
</div>

<!-- this one will not become hidden. -->
<div>not hidden..</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a `JavaScript` mixed approach.

**Steps**

```
1. Select all html nodes.
2. Search the nodes for the class name 'productPage'
3. If the class name is found, from the next node onward start adding the hidden class.
```

By doing the above procedure, the complete node list which are under a particular class name will be vanished from the DOM. No matter whats the hierarchy of the DOM is

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    const allNodes = $('*'); // Select all HTML nodes
    let itemIndex = null;
    allNodes.map((index, node) => {
      node.className &&
      node.className.indexOf('productPage') > -1 &&
      itemIndex === null
        ? (itemIndex = index)
        : itemIndex !== null
        ? (node.className += ' hidden')
        : null;
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div>
    <div>Will Stay</div>
    <div class="productPage">Product Page</div>
    <div>is hidden</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div>not hidden..</div>
<button>button</button>
```

I hope this is what you are looking for.